# How to maintain global variables in KnockoutJs throughout the application?

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, oracle-jet

I have a container page Index.html(this can be treated as a master page) in which I load different pages Home.html, people.html and each page is having its own viewmodel js file (Home.js, people.js). I navigate from Home.html to People.html. In Home.js I make an Ajax call and I need the data it fetches in People.js when I go to People.html page. I have tried using PublishOn and SubscribeTo but dint yield the results, I have tried creating a variable in main.js and thought of using it in both Home.js and people.js, I am able to access it by using $root. but I can do this only in Html page but not in Js.
Hope  I am clear with my problem statement.
**Note:**I am using RequireJs as well for configuration.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I am not sure i understand your problem correctly. You have some data stored in home.js viewmodel and you need to access this data from other viewmodel after redirect? Or it is actually a single page and you have both viewmodels loaded and you only need to access these viewmodels from each other?

Comment: "In Home.js I make an Ajax call and I need the data it fetches in People.js..." - that's where you lost me.  It sounds to me like you _should_ be able to add a variable to the container (you haven't explained where `main.js` is used) and access it from either view-model. Perhaps you're adding it to or accessing it from the wrong scope?

Comment: @Martin: You have some data stored in home.js viewmodel and you need to access this data from other viewmodel after redirect? "Yes". I am not loading both the pages at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is truly global, one way is to create a new AMD/RequireJS module that you then identify as a dependency in the ViewModels for `Home.html` and `People.html`. You then let this shared module manage the data. I would be tempted to move the Ajax call from Home's ViewModel into this new shared module.

Using `$root` creates an implicit contract between your views. Some would say this is hard to maintain and that it is better to document relationships through child view parameters. If the data is not global, but only shared between two child views of a specific view, then you can pass data to child views through parameters. Are you using Knockout components or Oracle JET modules? Both allow you to pass parameters from a parent View to a child ViewModel.

Comment: Passing Dependency parameter for ViewModels has done the job for me!! thanks :-)